# Google Sheets API Node clear filter

Tags: node.js, google-sheets, google-api

I am creating a function that clears the date from my Google sheet without delete the first row.
The first row is used as title headers for the column.

My Google sheet viewers can filter the data, but I want to clear the filters when I update the data.

For clearing the data I am doing the following:

```js
const request = {
      'spreadsheetId': spreadsheetId,
      resource: {
          'ranges': selectedRanges,
      },
  };

sheets.spreadsheets.values.batchClear(request, function (err, response) {
...
}
```

Clearing the data works well

How can I clear the filters as well in this request?

Thank you,
Moshe S.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### To clear a filter you need to use the method [spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate) instead of methods for [spreadsheets.values](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values)

More specifically, you need the [ClearBasicFilterRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#clearbasicfilterrequest) request.

It would look as following:

```js
  const request = {
    spreadsheetId: spreadsheetId, 
    resource: {
      requests: [{
      "clearBasicFilter": {
        "sheetId": sheetId
      }
    }], 
    },
    auth: authClient,
  };

sheets.spreadsheets.batchUpdate(request, function (err, response) {
  ...
  }
)
```

For more information on working with filters see also [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/filters).

Comment: Thank you, once I understood the difference between "spreadsheetId: spreadsheetId", and '"sheetId": sheetId"' things started to work.
My Google sheet has many tabs (sub sheets) is there a way to clear the filter from  all tabs?

Comment: You can implement multiple requests within one call to `spreadsheets.batchUpdate` - a request for each sheet with the respective `sheetId`. To find all your sheets (and their ids) you can make a call to [spreadsheets.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get)